# get all active Session in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

i used this code to get all Active Session in my asp.net Website, each user when login to my website will have  `Session["ID"]` , `IDsList` in code below will be something like `1,12,30,100,` that those numbers are active users IDs. my code works Fine on localhost but when i run my website on a windows Server 2008, it dose not workS. what should i do ?

```
  object obj = typeof(HttpRuntime).GetProperty("CacheInternal", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null, null);
        object[] obj2 = (object[])obj.GetType().GetField("_caches", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(obj);
        for (int i = 0; i < obj2.Length; i++)
        {
            Hashtable c2 = (Hashtable)obj2[i].GetType().GetField("_entries", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(obj2[i]);
            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in c2)
            {
                object o1 = entry.Value.GetType().GetProperty("Value", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(entry.Value, null);
                if (o1.GetType().ToString() == "System.Web.SessionState.InProcSessionState")
                {
                    SessionStateItemCollection sess = (SessionStateItemCollection)o1.GetType().GetField("_sessionItems", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(o1);
                    if (sess != null)
                    {
                        if (sess["ID"] != null)
                        {
                          IDsList += sess["ID"] + ",";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: are you getting any errors ?

Comment: @AliShahrokhi no nothing